# Unable to move object upwards at exact point - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new in unity. Here is my scenario which I want to implement.

I have a enemy and a tower.
Enemy collides with tower and move to the top of tower to escape from it.
I am unable to move enemy at exact position of towers top.

here is my code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) {

moveY = tf.position.y + 6; //6 is the height of tower
tf.Translate(0, moveY, 0, Space.World);

}
```

If I use position instead of translate it moves to towers top position, but I want to walk the enemy towards top of tower. Using translate moves enemy more towards bottom. Pls help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is your code doesn't recognize `tf`. try this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) 
{

moveY = collider.position.y + 6; //6 is the height of tower
collider.Translate(0, moveY, 0, Space.World);

}
```

If it is gameobject `tf` that is colliding, `tf` will be the collider. You will want to put in a if condition check to ensure the collider is `tf`.

Comment: As a sidenote, you might want to try answers.unity3d.com. Its the stack exchange site specifically for Unity3D.